# Execution of different videos on the same view

Tags: android

I need to know how to enable and disable at will the event

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new  MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener ()  {
  public  void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp) {
  }  
});
```

To not be invoked at all times
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use a completion listener, do not register one.

If you want to remove an existing completion listener, call `setOnCompletionListener(null)`.

Comment: Thank you.                                                       And if then I want to activate this listener again?

Comment: @RodolfoCidLazo: Call `setOnCompletionListener()` with your listener at that point.